# Unique selections in with multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, if-statement, tabs, each

This is intended to be a tabbed ui that could be applied to more than one element on the same page.

It works except for one bug:
That is, it will show and hide it's own tabs but for some reason when clicking the second tab it changes the status of all the tabs.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>super tabbed menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sub').click(
function () {

$('.mydiv', this).show();
$('.sub2. div').hide();

});


$('.sub2').click(
function () {

$('.mydiv2', this).show();

$('.sub div').hide();       
});

 });

</script>
<style>
.sub{float:left;padding-left:10px;}

.sub2{float:left;padding-left:10px;}
.mydiv{display:none;position:absolute; float:left;}
.mydiv2{display:none;position:absolute;background-color:grey;float:left;}
.showit{display:block}
</style>

</head>
<body>


  <div class="sub">
  <a class="thing" href="#" >this thing will make only one thing appear</a>
    <div class="mydiv">mydiv</div>  
</div>

     <div class="sub2">
     <a class="thing2" href="#" >this thing will make only one thing appear</a>
     <div class="mydiv2">mydiv2</div>  
    </div>


  </div>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<!--  ************************ -->
  <div class="sub">
  <a class="thing" href="#" >this thing will make only one thing appear</a>
    <div class="mydiv">mydiv</div>  
</div>

     <div class="sub2">
     <a class="thing2" href="#" >this thing will make only one thing appear</a>
     <div class="mydiv2">mydiv2</div>  
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $('.sub2. div') will select all tags with sub2 classes, including the one in the second tab menu, I change the the selector to prev() and next() and it seems to work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kswishaq/2yZYT/

However, one restriction for this solution is that sub2 has to come after sub1. To solve that, I would recommend you to wrap you tabs in a div, so you can call siblings("sub") to select the nearby tabs.

p.s.There are two extra  tags in your html codes.

Comment: THANK YOU I am still new to traversing dom to get what I want. I was playing around with prev/next and got confused over ,this and (this), any tutorials that you can recommend.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask, do you have any links, resources ideas about what to do if I wanted to try something like this for several elements that needed tabs like this?

Comment: this is the dom elements which doesn't have jquery properties and methods, and $(this) is jquery object. [A tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this)

Comment: I also found this thread in stack overflow to be useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244530/jquery-convert-to-work-with-multiple-tabs-on-one-page